# Is Sencha Touch Grid available without buying a bundle?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've been looking for an example of a Grid in Sencha Touch with out any success, and just read 
"Touch Grid is available as part of Sencha Complete or the Sencha Touch Bundle." 
http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-touch-2-3-html5-for-ios7-touch-grid-cordova-support-more/

Does this means that it is not available witout buying any of the above ?

Does anyone knows of a good tutorial in case it is available ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it looks like it is part of Sencha Complete or Sencha touch Bundle.
I have upgraded my workspace with Sencha 2.3 but I dont find grid support in that.

Comment: why does they keep saying "Sencha Touch grid is available in the Sencha Touch bundle and in Sencha Complete" like if otherwise it is not available ?